# How do I get a list of MongoDB documents that are referenced inside another collection

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, mapreduce, doctrine-odm

I am trying to find a way to get a list of MongoDB documents that are referenced in a subdocument in another collection.

I have a collection with user documents. In another collection I keep a list of businesses. Every business has a subdocument containing a list of references to users.

**The User collection:**

```
/* user-1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54e5e78680c7e191218b49b0"),
    "username" : "jachim@example.com",
    "password" "$2y$13$21p6hx3sd200cko4o0w04u46jNv3tNl3qpVWVbnAyzZpDxsSVDDLS"
}
/* user-2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54e5e78480c7e191218b49ab"),
    "username" : "jachim@example.net",
    "password" : "$2y$13$727amk1a7fwo4sgw8kkkcuWi4vhj2zKvZZIEDWtDQLo6dUjb0YnYy",
}
```

**The Business collection**

```
/* business-1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54e5e78880c7e191218b4c52"),
    "name" : "Stack Overflow",
    "users" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "User",
            "$id" : ObjectId("54e5e78680c7e191218b49b0"),
            "$db" : "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can get the user from a business by following the references in the business.users list, I can get the businesses from a user with the `db.Business.find({"users.$id": ObjectId("54e5e78480c7e191218b49ab")})` query, but **I cannot create a query to find all users that are referenced somewhere in a business**.

I can do this client side in two steps:

```
db.Business.distinct("users.$id");
```

Which will return a list of user ids. This list I can use in a query to the user collection:

```
db.User.find({ _id: { $in: [ LIST_OF_IDS ] } });
```

But this could result in very big queries (potentially leading to queries larger than 16MB).

I think MapReduce would be a solution for this, but I'm not quite sure what fields I should use there.

Any experts here on this?

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? You should not have keys beginning with `$` - it's illegal to insert such documents in current versions of MongoDB.

Comment: Those are valid DBRefs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs

Comment: How did you make them? Again - what version of MongoDB are you using? I know this seems orthogonal to the question but you will have trouble writing queries on fields whose names start with `$`. Normally DBRefs do not appear that way in the shell or in drivers that support them.

Comment: The version is 2.6.7 and the references are made via the Doctrine ODM (http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodbref.php).

Comment: Where the documents created with MongoDB at 2.6? How do you get the documents to display like the above, with the `$ref` and `$id`, etc, that way? I can't replicate that behavior with 2.6 and I cannot insert fields with `$` at the beginning - it's not supposed to be valid. I'm sorry to go off on a tangent but I want to figure out if there's something fishy going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and a chat on the MongoDB IRC channel, there are several options to get this to work:

1. Go with the `$in` query.
2. Keep track of the relation on both sides (a little harder to keep the relations up to date on both sides, but it works).
3. Change the owning side of the relation (keeping track of businesses in the user document), but this depends on the nature of your queries.

The [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) would not work, because it cannot query multiple collections, nor will [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/) (for the same reason, although [it is possible](http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/)).