# Deleting documents that are not indexed in another collection in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

First, I have read a few answers (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610445/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-mongodb-documents-that-are-referenced-inside-another-coll) one), but I'm not sure how I can implement this in Meteor.

I have a collection of `items`, and another of `categories`. Categories are created dynamically when the items are saved. Once the document is saved, I want to cleanup all categories that no longer are associated with an item. How do I do that? I'm used to SQL, and I haven't worked much with document-based DBs other than indexers like Lucene.

For example, given two `items` like

```
{ _id: "RK9kQSD7frgreYDvg", name: "Item 1", catId: "c4mE7hANtbWxHFAdm" }
{ _id: "569aogaGBYBMonkgg", name: "Item 2", catId: "c4mE7hANtbWxHFAdm" }
```

and two `categories` like

```
{ _id: "mu2KzDbNdTcrZYGKs", name: "Cat A" }
{ _id: "c4mE7hANtbWxHFAdm", name: "Cat B" }
```

I want to remove `"Cat A"` since it is no longer referenced by any `items`.

I guess something like

```
const Items = new Meteor.Collection('items');
const Categories = new Meteor.Collection('categories');

...

Categories.remove({ _id: { $not: { $in: ... } });
```

but I'm not sure from that point.

Comment: I don't think MongoDB supports the idea of a table join or subqueries, so the easiest way would be to grab all unique IDs from Items and remove all Categories no `$in` that list.  But, that seems very inefficient, and maybe impractical depending on how many documents are in your Items collection.  You might also look at aggregation.  I looked through the MongoDB documentation, and I didn't see any reason why you couldn't use an aggregate function inside a delete filter, but someone with more MongoDB experience might need to speak up.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you on that. I'm just not sure how I can do that in an efficient way. There should not be more than a few thousand items, but I'd like to know anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly in the right direction though you may need to use the **[`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)** operator in your remove query.

The first query returns all the distinct values of the `catId` from the `items` collection in a list. You can just use underscore.js **[`uniq()`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)** method, which comes with Meteor and the **[`map()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-map)** cursor method to create the distinct array. The second operation will then use that list to delete entries in the `categories` collection.

The following example demonstrates the above:

```
const Items = new Meteor.Collection('items');
const Categories = new Meteor.Collection('categories');
const catIds = _.uniq(Items.find‌​({}).map((item) => item.catId;)); 

Categories.remove({ "_id": { "$nin": catIds } });
```

Comment: This works, and I don't expect to have too many items in that collection. Thanks!